# Suppressing various tex output files

Tags: output

Each time I use Texmaker, it creates a host of files that are not immediately useful for me (*.log, *.dvi, *.blg, *.bbl, *.gz). Is there any way to 'hide' these files? They can cause quite a clutter. Thanks!

Comment: not necessarily applicable to your case, but if you don't need `.aux`, `.toc` or "list of" files, they can be suppressed by the command `\nofiles` in the preamble.  don't know any way of suppressing a `.log` file though.  the `.blg` and `.bbl` are associated with bibtex, not latex, and `.gz` is entirely separate!

Comment: They _are_ useful to you as they are required for getting the output (dvi)  getting the typeset bibliography (bbl) being able to link from the output to the source (gz, most likely) and debugging if things go wrong(log,blg)

Comment: Texmaker have item `clean` in `tools` menu that does this